# Creating block tridiagonal matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am writing a Matlab code for a solution to a non-linear partial differential equations. I reached a point where I need an (M+1)^2 by (M+1)^2 block matrix containing say A as the main diagonal, B in position (i,i+1) while C in (i,i+2). i.e., B and C are above the main diagonal A.
Is there a short way to build such block matrices?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can build a single block using [triu](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) function like this:

```
M = 4;
A = 2; B = 3; C = 4;
onesMat = ones(M+1,M+1);
block = A*eye(M+1) + B*(triu(onesMat,1)-triu(onesMat,2)) + C*(triu(onesMat,2)-triu(onesMat,3));

block =
     2     3     4     0     0
     0     2     3     4     0
     0     0     2     3     4
     0     0     0     2     3
     0     0     0     0     2
```

If my understanding is correct and you want to create a block-diagonal matrix by repeating the same block `M+1` times, you can use `blkdiag` for that:

```
blocks = repmat({block}, M+1, 1);
res = blkdiag(blocks{:});
```

Comment: this is what I get after running your codes:
[5x5 double]
    [5x5 double]
    [5x5 double]
    [5x5 double]
    [5x5 double]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `res`, the result of `blkdiag`, is a 25x25 block-diagonal matrix. If you mean that `blocks` is a cell array of `M+1` matrices - yes, of course. We need them to combine into a single block-diagonal matrix using `blkdiag`.

Comment: Okay if I understand you, you mean the block matrix is formed, only that it isn't displayed?

Comment: Of course nothing is displayed.. there's a semicolon at the end of each statement. _Not_ suppressing the output with `;` is a very bad practice. `block` is also not displayed by the actual code - I just included it here to illustrate the output. Displaying 25x25 matrix would obviously only make the answer less readable.